# HBase: Does copy pasting the directories work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hbase, hdfs

I'm planning to get a hadoop/hbase cluster up and I'm trying to figure out what ec2 intance type to use and how much EBS space.

I'm going initially with

- 1 master (m1.small)
- 2 slaves (m1.small)

I'm not expecting more than 100 simultaneous users on my website (Is this no big?)

Well, I would attach 20 GB EBS blocks to each of master and slaves. These EBS blocks will contain the data storage and logs from HDFS and HBase.

The path of hbase should look like `/mnt/hadoop/hbase/root` where `/mnt/hadoop` is the directory where `EBS block` (for e.g. `/dev/sda`) will be mounted

Eventually, this space will be filled and when I realize that 20 GB is less I would create a 60 GB (`/dev/sdb`) lets say and attach it the disk. Now, I'll copy everything from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` and finally mount `/dev/sdb` to `/mnt/hadoop`

Does, HDFS/HBase see any difference after this change? Is it legal to do in this way or discouraged?

How do we increase the storage of the device the HBase/HDFS write its data?

Comment: Take a look at Amazon Elastic MapReduce. It has HBase option that takes care of your backup and restore and other admin tasks

Comment: @Guy: We can't have m1.small instances in HBase on EMR. Can we?

Comment: No. The smallest for HBase is m1.large: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hbase-launch.html

Comment: If you don't need a lot of traffic, you can also check DynamoDB as you can use its free tier with such small capacity

Answer (score 0):

Neither HBase nor Hadoop stops you from doing that. It's merely changing your configuration parameters accordingly. You need to be careful though.

But why would you do that, when you are sure that you are going to hit the limits?Prevention is better than cure, IMHO.